# Best dwarf shrub varieties which has shallow roots to plant near building wall

Tags: plant-recommendations, hedge, invasive, wall, foundation

I'd like to grow oleanders that won't impact the wall or foundation of my building.

I noticed that dwarf oleanders could be a solution as it's known not to grow more than 3 feet tall. ( [Click here to understand more about my building](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252733/142629) )

I guess root system will not be complicated like going deep or invasive.

I have available space of just 2 feet from the building wall. I'd like to develop a hedge along the 60 feet length of the building.

If not hedge at least some good looking plants along the boundary of my building.

Below are some of the Dwarf Oleander I found online but I couldn't get enough information about root system. As I have very less empty space  I have to think thoroughly before I plant.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some help would be appreciated.

Please feel free to recommend me plants.

Comment: Can you tell us what area of the world you live in?

Comment: South asian subcontinent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider installing , **tree root barriers** to invasive roots from damaging your foundation or sewer lines etc..

It might be an expensive option but still good one.

Please find root barrier below

[image]

likewise the root barriers are available in plastic , concrete materials as well.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as links may disappear, especially a video.  You could improve your answer by adding the main details to your answer.

Comment: How deep should the root barrier be ?

Comment: I'd imagine it should be as deep as foundation